# Send variable through tmux binding

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to setup a tmux (1.9) key-binding to swap to windows.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out a way to send a variable for the swap.  For example, if you hit C-b . It will then prompt where to move the window to.  How can I get the same behavior with swap?

I have:

```
bind-key > swap-window -t {something else here...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  The best way to do it is to use the command-prompt feature.

> bind > command-prompt -p "swap with" "swap-window -t '%%'"